# Excel automatic rating

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation

OK , so let's say I have a list of movie titles. Say for simplicity's sake that there's 5 movie titles. On the next column, I have ratings based on my opinion for the movies,from 1 to 5 because there are 5 titles.
Here's an example:

Movie A -> 2
Movie B ->  1
Movie C ->  3
Movie D ->  5
Movie E ->  4

Now say I want to add a new movie with a rating of 3 , since I liked it better than Movie C,D and E.

Movie F -> 3

Since I'll now have
Movie C -> 3 and Movie F -> 3
the ratings are gonna have to change, right? So what I'm looking for is a command or formula which I can use in order to automatically make:

- Movie C get a rating of 4 (3+1)
- Movie D get a rating of 6(5+1)
- Movie E get a rating of 5 (4+1)

So the list right after I add "Movie F -> 3" will update itself to

Movie A ->  2
Movie B ->  1
Movie C ->  4
Movie D ->  6
Movie E ->  5
Movie F -> 3

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of ***u1016274***'s code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
   v = Target.Value
   addy = Target.Address(0, 0)
   Application.EnableEvents = False
      For Each r In Intersect(Range("B:B"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
         If r.Address(0, 0) <> addy And r.Value >= v Then
            r.Value = r.Value + 1
         End If
      Next r
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

So if we started with:

[image]

and added *Raging Bull* as number 3, we would have:

[image]

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: I tried it and it worked perfectly. It's a bit unsteady since it goes haywire if you delete some value and leave the cell blank but it's more than I could have hoped for. thank you very much for all your help and for being so detailed in your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my idea (no code).
1. Write a VBA routine that is run when a value in column B is changed ("Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)").
2. check Target to be a cell in column B.
3. save the current selection's value in a variable

```
new = Selection.value
```

4. compare all cell values in column B from row 1 to the last non-empty row if it is greater or equal to the new value. If equal, if it is in the same row as the selection, skip it. For all other cases, increment the value by 1.

Comment: thank you for your answer! as I'm not really familiar with vba scripting I preferred copying the code from below